# Deploying MVC 3 website on Windows Server 2003 with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, windows-server-2003, windows-authentication

I have deployed an MVC 3 website on IIS of my Windows Server 2003 edition. I have set the authentication to Basic, Integrated, and Windows in order to enable site to use Windows authentication, and automatically log in into website if the user has launched the site from the same domain. If user access the site from another domain, it should prompt the Windows credentials and should allow user to log in.
However the problem is that, user is presented with Windows login prompt every time (irrespective to same or different domain), and also when user provides valid credentials it doesn't allow user to access the site.

What could be the problem here? Or, can anyone provide me proper guide to configure IIS to use Windows Authentication while deployed on Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the version of IIS you are using ? Could you try to force NTLM authentication and see whether it will change anything ? Followin technet article will tell you how to change to NTML http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7258232a-5e16-4a83-b76e-11e07c3f2615.mspx?mfr=true. Please backup the server/iis configs before attempting any modifications to the metabase